# Negative values in the data set

Tags: curve-fitting

I have a set of negative values and would like to put a fitted model in R. How would I approach it? Say, I want to use Gamma distribution as a fitted curve using method of moments but the data is all negative and thus, it leads to the negative rate.

Comment: Why not multiply everything by -1, then proceed as usual?

Comment: What does the data look like?(/What model do you mean?) (e.g. a shifted gamma ($Y=X-\theta$), or a flipped gamma($Y=-X$), or a flipped shifted gamma($Y=\theta-X$), or something else?)

Comment: Thank you Nick and Glen, it does help here. I was afraid of using the transformation $Y=-X$.